# Speed up an R function

Tags: r, function

I made this function to prepare my quantitative dataframe/matrix for next operations:

```
fun<-function(x,i) {
    if(i<nrow(x)) {
      x[i+1,]<-x[i,]+x[i+1,]
      fun(x,i+1)
    }
    else return(x)
  }
library(vegan)
data(mite)
x<-fun(mite,1)
```

It works fine, but is slow. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Could you add some sample data, usage and what the function does(an example with output on sample data)?

Comment: (1) R does not do tail-recursion efficiently, I suggest you look into https://tailrecursion.com/wondr/posts/tail-recursion-in-r.html. (2) What NelsonGon said. (3) You are using `nrow` suggesting frames, but it seems you are doing matrix-like math, which might be dangerous. (4) Based on the code, though, I suspect this can be done using `zoo::rollapply` (and `lapply`).

Comment: Do you mean `as.data.frame(lapply(mite, cumsum))`?

Comment: @symbolrush, I don't see how `x` would grow in this function, as it terminates when `i` is not less than the number of rows, so there is no extension. And since the comparison is of single numbers, how would vectorizing help the conditional?

Comment: as.data.frame(lapply(mite, cumsum)) works correctly and faster, thank you r2evans

Answer (score 3):

You should generally avoid recursion in R. Try using `cumsum` instead:

```
fun1 <- function(x, i) {

  f <- function(x, i) {
    y <- x
    y[i:length(y)] <- cumsum(y[i:length(y)])
    y
  }

  x <- as.matrix(x)
  apply(x, 2, f, i = i) 
}

x <- matrix(rnorm(10),ncol = 2)
all.equal(fun(x, 3), fun1(x, 3))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Do you even need `fun1`? I'd think `lapply(x, cumsum)` would suffice.

Comment: No, she starts the cumulative sum at row i.